# GET variables in WordPress keeps going to 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress with a custom crm for a 2 part form.

When I send the first form data through from the form on the homepage it returns a customer ID in the URL to the second form page. However, the &recordid=xx makes wordpress returna 404 page.

How do I make the page not through a 404?

Original form second page: http://mysites.com/get-personalized-quote

Original form second page with variable: http://mysite.com/get-personalized-quote&recordid=2763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `?recordid=2763` instead of `&recordid=2763`

note the `?`